# Expand large polynomial with Sage (List colouring, combinatorial Nullstellensatz)

Tags: graph, sage

Disclaimer: I have no experience with sage, programming or any computer calculations.

I want to expand a polynomial in Sage. The input is a factored polynomial and I need a certain coefficient. However, since the polynomial has 30 factors, my computer won't do it.

Should I look for somebody with a better computer or are 30 factors simply too much?

Here is my sage code:

```
R.<x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9,x_10,x_11,x_12> = QQbar[]

f = (x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3)*(x_1-x_9)*(x_1-x_10)*(x_2-x_3)*(x_2-x_10)*(x_2-x_11)*(x_2-x_12)*(x_3-x_4)*(x_4-x_11)*(x_4-x_5)*(x_4-x_6)*(x_4-x_11)*(x_5-x_6)*(x_5-x_10)*(x_5-x_11)*(x_5-x_12)*(x_6-x_7)*(x_6-x_12)*(x_7-x_9)*(x_7-x_8)*(x_7-x_12)*(x_8-x_9)*(x_8-x_10)*(x_8-x_11)*(x_8-x_12)*(x_9-x_10)*(x_10-x_11)*(x_10-x_12)*(x_11-x_12);

c = f.coefficient({x_1:2,x_2:2,x_3:2,x_4:2,x_5:2,x_6:2,x_7:2,x_8:2,x_9:2,x_10:5,x_11:5,x_12:5}); c
```

Just some background. I'm trying to solve an instance of list edge colouring with the combinatorial Nullstellensatz.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_edge-coloring

Given a graph G=(V,E) we associate a variable x_i with each vertex i in V. The graph monomial eps(G) is defined as the product \prod_{ij \in E} (x_i-x_j). (Note that we fixed an orientation of the edges, but that's not important here.)

Suppose that there are lists of colours assigned to the vertices, such that the vertex i has a list of size a(i). Then, by the combinatorial Nullenstellensatz there is a colouring from those lists (i.e. each vertex receives a colour from its list and two adjacent vertices do not receive the same colour), if the coefficient of \prod_{i \in V} x_i^{a(i)-1} is non-zero in eps(G).

I want to apply this to the line graph of the graph G(M) with incidence matrix:

```
M = Matrix([0,0,0,3,3,0,3],[0,0,0,0,3,3,3],[0,0,0,3,0,3,3],[0,0,0,3,3,0,3],[3,0,3,0,0,0,6],[3,3,0,0,0,0,6],[0,3,3,0,0,0,6],[3,3,3,6,6,6,0])
```

(Here the size of the lists are indicated by the integers).

Comment: I'm even having trouble getting `f` to print; this is definitely puzzling...

Comment: The expanded polynomial's really, really big.  But are you sure the coefficient isn't going to be identically zero?  There seem to be 30 terms in your `f`, but the sum of the values of your coefficient argument seems to be 33.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it takes so long because your coefficients are in QQbar, and arithmetic in QQbar is much slower than over QQ, for example.  Is there a good reason for not using QQ?

If I change the coefficient ring to QQ, Sage fairly quickly tells me that c is 0:

```
sage: R.<x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9,x_10,x_11,x_12> = QQ[]  
sage: f = (x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3)*(x_1-x_9)*(x_1-x_10)*(x_2-x_3)*(x_2-x_10)*(x_2-x_11)*(x_2-x_12)*(x_3-x_4)*(x_4-x_11)*(x_4-x_5)*(x_4-x_6)*(x_4-x_11)*(x_5-x_6)*(x_5-x_10)*(x_5-x_11)*(x_5-x_12)*(x_6-x_7)*(x_6-x_12)*(x_7-x_9)*(x_7-x_8)*(x_7-x_12)*(x_8-x_9)*(x_8-x_10)*(x_8-x_11)*(x_8-x_12)*(x_9-x_10)*(x_10-x_11)*(x_10-x_12)*(x_11-x_12)
sage: c = f.coefficient({x_1:2,x_2:2,x_3:2,x_4:2,x_5:2,x_6:2,x_7:2,x_8:2,x_9:2,x_10:5,x_11:5,x_12:5})
sage: c
0
```